# Unable to connect with PC using USB connection after upgrading to Lollipop 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb, micromax-yu-yureka

I am using Micromax Yu Yureka. I'm unable to connect with PC using USB connection after recently upgrading my device to Lollipop 5.0.2. But it was working in Kitkat perfectly.

Comment: Do you see a notification to select USB type in Android when you connect into PC ? What options are present and which one is selected?

Answer (score -1):

go to settings>developers options>and check the USB debugging option.(it should be on).This might help or try hard factory reset.

Comment: Please back your claim, why USB debugging needs to be on for a simple USB connection? It seems you understood OP's question about "USB connection" as USB debugging and not data-transfer, which makes this answer useful. However, OP didn't say that, so please fill the details by yourself.